# cross domain post refresh clears session values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I have html something like this from http://fromDomain.com and posting to http://toDomain.com which is a rails application.

```
    <html>
    <h1>Test Redirect with Post</h1>
    <button id="submit" onclick="send_form()">Submit</button>

    <script>
    function send_form() {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
        form.setAttribute("action", 'http://todomain.com/someaction');
        form.appendChild(addElement('field1',  'field1'));
        form.appendChild(addElement('field2',  'field2)');
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();}

    function addElement(key, value){
       var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
       hiddenField.setAttribute("value", value);
       return hiddenField;}
    </script>
    </html>
```

In the rails application I am doing something like this.

```
def someaction

if  not session[:token]
 session[:token] = @self.getsomehash
end 
end
```

Problem is after http://todomain.com/someaction page loaded if users hits browser refresh then it will re post the page and session hash get reset.  Looks like I when browsers does a repost rails create a new session rather then using existing one.

Is my assumption right? Is there any way to allow refresh and still persist the values in anyway?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with RoR hosting environment, but sessions cookies (transient cookies) are generally stored on the user-agent to identify the visitor in these situations. This mechanism should be regardless to how RoR does its state management, server side. which browser are you using?

Comment: can you use the developer mode of your browser to determine that your browser is storing a session cookie for <http://todomain.com> when it first visits the page/site after the initial post?.. .. it should have a domain (Scope) value associated to the session cookie, if the first session cookie is being created, is it specifying <http://todomain.com> as the domain?.

Comment: I am using Chrome and I can use any browser for testing if you recommend one.  I will also check the domain scope.

Comment: Chrome is fine, use Developer Console [f12] > resources.. find and delete <http://todomain>.. then run your post, refresh test.. and see if and when the session cookie is created .. session cookies will have an expiration date of "<session>"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the [Redirect-on-POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern - basically you need to configure your server app to send a redirect in response to each POST request.